# communicate between the main app bundle and the framework it contains

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to pass data between 2 view controllers. One of the controllers resides in a framework and the other in the main app bundle. I am trying to use protocols to communicate between the two. I am able to import the protocol from the framework to the main app, but I am facing the issue that the information isn't getting communicated back. I need to set up a 2-way communication channel

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a protocol for the information that you want to communicate back and forth.

Let's say in `SampleFramework` you have

```
public protocol Information {
  var string: String { get }
}

public protocol Communicator {
  func provide(info: Information)
  func consume(info: Information)
}

public class MediaCompany {
  public var communicators: [Communicator] = []

  public func present(info: Information) {
    communicators.forEach { $0.provide(info: info) }
  }
}
```

So, in your main app target, you can do

```
import SampleFramework

struct Song: Information {
  var string: String { return "Merry Christmas" }
}

public class Singer: Communicator {
  func provide(info: Information) { print(info.string) }
  func consume(info: Information) { print(info.string) }
}

let aBigMediaCompany = MediaCompany()
aBigMediaCompany.communicators.append(Singer())
aBigMediaCompany.present(Song())
```

So it will print 
`Merry Christmas`

You can see in the code, `SampleFramework` provides the protocols and declare how to work with that.

Comment: is there a way I can set up communication from the main app to the framework?

Comment: Yes, you can. But I would need your case first before making an example with code.

Comment: So, I have a framework which has some ARKit functionality. This framework is contained in an app where the app controls what objects to show in the environment. So if I tap on let's say a candle in the app's view controller class, I want to communicate it to the framework that the model has now changed to a candle (Displaying and downloading the model will be taken care of the framework). I want to know how I communicate from app to framework

Comment: So it is simple as the code I wrote above. You can refer
* In the framework, you can have
- `Information` as `Model`
- `MediaCompany` as `ModelProcessor`

* In the main app, 
- `Song` as `Candle`

So, when you select the `Candle`, you can ask the `ModelProcessor` to perform the download and display the model.